# Create the DynamoDB global Table if doesn't exist using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am sharing the DynamoDB cft below. I want to add a condition, so that while adding the another table the existing tables will not impact. Below template is used for creating 2 global table with name as sample1 and sample12 configuring in parameter section:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: 'AWS CloudFormation Template for DynamoDB tables For sample Service'
Parameters:
  sample1:
    Type: String
    Description: Select existing dynamodb table name from Parameter Store
    Default: sample1
  sample12:
    Type: String
    Description: Select existing dynamodb table name from Parameter Store
    Default: sample12
Resources: 
  sample1: 
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable
    Properties:
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST      
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "msgId"
          AttributeType: "S" 
      KeySchema: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "msgId"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
        SSEType: "KMS"    
      Replicas:
      - Region: us-east-1        
      TableName: !Ref sample1
    
  sample12: 
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable
    Properties: 
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "msgId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "flightNbr"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "recordUpdateTS"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "msgTypeCd"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "recordCreationEpochTime"
          AttributeType: "S"         
      KeySchema: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "msgId"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
        SSEType: "KMS"    
      Replicas:
      - Region: us-east-1        
      TableName: !Ref sample12
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes: 
        - 
          IndexName: "FLIGHTNBR_UPDATETS_INDEX"
          KeySchema: 
             - 
              AttributeName: "flightNbr"
              KeyType: "HASH"
             - 
              AttributeName: "recordUpdateTS"
              KeyType: "RANGE"  
          Projection: 
            ProjectionType: "ALL"   
        - 
          IndexName: "MSGTYPE_CREATETS_INDEX"
          KeySchema: 
             - 
              AttributeName: "msgTypeCd"
              KeyType: "HASH"
             - 
              AttributeName: "recordCreationEpochTime"
              KeyType: "RANGE"  
          Projection: 
            ProjectionType: "ALL"
```

How can I add a condition or any other methods to check if table exists or not?

Comment: There's no condition that can be added that checks for the existence of a table.  You could use a parameter or a CustomResource to inform CF the existance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is through [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in the form of a **lambda function**. The function would use AWS SDK to perform conditional checks and create aws resources based on the outcome of these checks.